# how to use expo simulator for CRNA Create-React-Native-App?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

i was thinking that we only have two android emulator and also iOS simulator used to develop react native app through their android studio and xcode sdk.

but CRNA(Create React Native App) users can not use both emulator and simulators.

They can only run the app using a mobile device through Expo app.

Is there any simulator in expo for CRNA user ?

please suggest any idea to use simulator

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They make running the app on actual devices super easy and obvious, and I totally understand why you'd think it's not possible to run the app in the simulators as well. But, in fact, you can.

[Expo recommends using the Android Emulator in Genymotion](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/genymotion.html)

And if you open the project in the Expo IDE, you should see this option...
[image]

Comment: opening in Expo IDE is very slow...so what i want is i am running my project in sublime...through sublime i cant use any simulator? @Chris Geirman

Comment: Another "not very intuitive" thing about Expo is that it defaults to running your app through tunnel, which will always work but is also slow. If your device is on the same wifi, you can change that to LAN to speed it up. Localhost may also work. You'd still edit your project in sublime as you prefer. There's an image of this in their docs https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/debugging.html